# Consumer not recevng messages when consumers in one queue is busy

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

We have set up two exchanges, EX_1 and EX_2, in RabbitMQ, each with a single queue (SAMPLE_Q_1 and SAMPLE_Q_2, respectively) and 10 consumers. All those consumers are running in our spring web project

We sent 1000 messages to SAMPLE_Q_1, and all the consumers were occupied with processing these requests, with only 10 messages being processed simultaneously due to the limited number of consumers.

While this was running, we attempted to send a single message to SAMPLE_Q_2, but it did not appear to be received by any of the 10 available consumers in the RMQ Web console its showing as Unacked count as 1 (But messages are not receiving inside the handleDelivery method).

RabbitMQ Consumer not receiving messages in this block but.

```
public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag,
            Envelope envelope,
            AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
            byte[] body) throws IOException {
try{
// some code here
// added log here but nothing is printing
} finally {
           
            channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
        }
}
```

This behavior was observed to be working correctly on our local machine, but not on our Azure instance (Still not sure if this is an Azure instance issue or not).

Although both exchanges and queues operate independently one exchange won't impact the performance of the other we believe. we are unsure why there is a delay in processing messages. We would appreciate any assistance or insights on this issue.

We have some `thread.sleep` inside the consumer code that we removed from everywhere.